# Confusion with Literal term in Java

Tags: java, literals

I always come across the term literal.
What is that?

Is it that every primitive type variable is called as literal?

Answer (score 4):

Literal is any value, fixed, constant, used in your code.

For example:
    int a =0 ;

`0` is a literal. The value of "0" is *literally* 0.

Comment: I'm not really happy with this explanation. It does point out the use, but also mentions _constant_ which can surely add to the confusion of the OP. The last sentence isn't as clarifying either.

Comment: I'll happily remove my comment(s). There is just no other way to 'vent' my observations regarding your answer; the goal was not to spark discussion but to warn about potentially confusing wording.

Comment: @Wivani: :) no problem, wasn't the intention to "spark". But I assumed the OP just wanted a simple answer to clarify a little bit his question, not be the most precise answer. Exactly because the best definition is already in the Oracle docs, and he didn't got the idea from there...

Answer (score 3):

[Java Language Specification §3.10](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10):

> A *literal* is the source code representation of a value of a primitive type (§4.2), the String type (§4.3.3), or the null type (§4.1)...

Answer (score 2):

A literal is a string that is in quotes - basically a string in and of itself, not in a variable:

`string variable = "This is the literal section of the string";`

This makes the distinction between a string variable and a string literal. You need variables in your code, but you would like to remove literals out to an external file, so they are not compiled with the application and you can change them on the fly.

Comment: Not an exhaustive explanation about literals but +1 for the externalization advice.

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to assigning a value to a variable without the use of the new keyword (or referring to an already existing object).

See Oracle's [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) on primitive datatypes. Even though I'd try to refer to Oracle these days, the references in the other answers seem to be more exhaustive (also pointing to true and false for example).

Cheers,
Wim